# Is it possible to visit Openethereum JSON-RPC from external internet ( not from LAN )?

Tags: openethereum

as far as I know, it's very easy to send JSON-RPC request to a ETH node running with openethereum from LAN,

I want to know, what can I do to make this ETH node public, and allow people who is from external internet to visit?

e.g.  in `config.toml`

```
[rpc]
apis = ["all"]
port = 8080
interface = "0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: seems `interface = "all"` , I will try

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it .

```
[rpc]
apis = ["all"]
port = 8080
interface = "all"  # this will do the work!
```

according to: `openethereum -h`, we can see the argument explanation:

```
    --jsonrpc-interface=[IP]
        Specify the hostname portion of the HTTP JSON-RPC API server, IP should be an 
        interface's IP address, or all (all interfaces) or local. (default: local)
```